# Using pygsheets is it possible to get a url for each worksheet

Tags: pygsheets

Using `pygsheets` its possible to list all the `worksheet` objects in an account but is it possible to get either a sharing url or a direct url to each workbook?

Answer (score 0):

The google sheets url is of the format

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<spreadsheet id>/edit#gid=<worksheet id>
```

so you can build it using pygsheets as follows

```
url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ssheet.id+"/edit#gid="+wks.id
```